# Stateful React component with async function failing Jest test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'm following along in this [Jest test tutorial on Pluralsight here](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=testing-react-applications-jest&author=daniel-stern&name=f31785ac-30f9-4d02-aab6-473c85ce6770&clip=8&mode=live). And I've written code exactly like the author, but for some reason my test is not passing.

**My Pull request to the author's repo: https://github.com/danielstern/isomorphic-react/pull/19**

I have a simple React component, it updates it's `count` state with a async/await call to a service within the `componentDidMount`.

```
{this.state.count != -1 ? `${this.state.count} Notifications Awaiting` : 'Loading...'}
```

### EXPECTED

Since I've mocked the NotificationsService, and set count to `42`, the test should pass with text inside the component being `"42 Notifications Awaiting!"`

### RESULTS

The text stays stuck as the default `Loading...`

I've mocked the service correctly, and the `count` variable is even being logged correctly as `42`! However `this.state.count` is still `-1` so instead of displaying: `${this.state.count} Notifications Awaiting` it still displays `Loading...` and thus fails the test.

---

### What I've tried

1) I've tried adding 1000 into the delay.

2) Tried using setTimeout inside the test.

3) Tried `jest.useFakeTimers();` and `jest.runAllTimers();`

However nothing is working, the `count` inside of the component is stuck at `-1` even though `count` is set to 42. It just seems to me that my test is running before the state is finished being set?

[image]

### The NotificationsViewser.jsx Component

```
import React from 'react';
import NotificationsService from '../services/NotificationsService';

export default class componentName extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);

    this.state = {
      count: -1
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount () {
    let { count } = await NotificationsService.GetNotifications();
    console.log('count:', count);
    this.setState({
      count
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('componentDidUpdate:', this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="mt-3 mb-2">
        <div className="notifications">
          {this.state.count != -1 ? `${this.state.count} Notifications Awaiting` : `Loading...`}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

### NotificationsService.js

```
import { delay } from 'redux-saga';

export default {
  async GetNotifications() {
    console.warn("REAL NOTIFICATION SERVICE! CONTACTING APIS!");

    await delay(1000);
    return { count: 42 };
  }
}
```

### **mocks**: NotificationsService.js

```
let count = 0;

export default {
  __setCount(_count) {
    count = _count;
  },
  async GetNotifications() {
    console.warn("GOOD JOB! USING MOCK SERVICE");
    return { count };
  }
}
```

Finally...

### The Test

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import delay from 'redux-saga';

import NotificationsViewer from '../NotificationsViewer';

jest.mock('../../services/NotificationsService');

const notificationService = require('../../services/NotificationsService').default;

describe('The notification viewer', () => {

  beforeAll(() => {
    notificationService.__setCount(42);
  });

  it('should display the correct number of notifications', async() => {
    const tree = renderer
      .create(
        <NotificationsViewer/>
      );

    await delay();

    const instance = tree.root;
    const component = instance.findByProps({className: `notifications`});
    const text = component.children[0];
    console.log('text is:', text);

    expect(text).toEqual('42 Notifications Awaiting!');
  });
})
```

Comment: It seems to me that the `await delay()` is not letting the life cycle methods run first before the `expect` block is tested. Because the results of `console.log('text is:', text);` are hit first, then the `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` logs are hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the real problem was in `isomorphic-react/src/components/__tests__/NotificationsViewer.js` file. The `delay` are imported the wrong way and that was causing the error on test.

If importing `delay` like this: `import { delay } from 'redux-saga'` fix the problem. =D

Comment: This is correct, I had the import wrong. Leaving my answer below as a preferred way to handle this however, as not every project will be using `redux-saga` and my example explains how to use Enzyme to solve this issue :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that `await delay()` did not work to let all the React life cycle methods like `componentDidMount` instantiate / get called.

I had to result to using `Enzyme` even though the author did not recommend it due to a lot of open bug issues.

Using Enzyme I could ensure that the `componentDidMount` was called, and thus setting the state of `count` to `42` with the mocked service.

I also needed to installed the following packages:

```
"enzyme": "^3.10.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.14.0",
```

### Fixed test

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { shallow, configure } from 'enzyme';

configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

import NotificationsViewer from './NotificationsViewer';

jest.mock('../services/NotificationsService');

const notificationService = require('../services/NotificationsService').default;

notificationService.default = jest.fn();

describe('The notification viewer', () => {

  beforeAll(() => {
    notificationService.__setCount(42);
  });

  // it('pass', () => {});

  it('should display the correct number of notifications', async() => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<NotificationsViewer />);
    const wrapper = shallow(<NotificationsViewer />);
    const instance = tree.root;

    await wrapper.instance().componentDidMount();

    const component = instance.findByProps({className: `notifications`});
    const text = component.children[0];
    console.log('text is:', text);

    expect(text).toEqual('42 Notifications Awaiting');
  });
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `describe` also needs to be an async function? `await` statements need to be declared inside an `async` scope, no?

Comment: Ok so I just tried that but got this warning
> Returning a Promise from "describe" is not supported. Tests must be defined synchronously.
        Returning a value from "describe" will fail the test in a future version of Jest.

Comment: Ops, I missed the `async` on the `it` block